# failures when rails command send

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rbenv

I am trying to open an old Rails 5 app. I haven't code for years and it's hard to remember...
Also I have a new computer (mac 0S Ventura) and I had to reinstall hombrew, xcode, ruby etc...
The ruby version of this app was `ruby '2.4.4'`

I am fixing little by little the problems but I am stuck there:

when I run any rails command...

```
rails s                                                                                                                                                   [(3.2.2)]
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.2.1 application starting in development 
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Exiting
/Users/nelly/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/type/adapter_specific_registry.rb:9:in `add_modifier': wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 2) (ArgumentError)
    from /Users/nelly/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/type.rb:27:in `add_modifier'
    from /Users/nelly/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:834:in `<class:PostgreSQLAdapter>'
    from /Users/nelly/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:72:in `<module:ConnectionAdapters>'
    from /Users/nelly/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:44:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
    from /Users/nelly/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:22:in `<main>'
    from <internal:/Users/nelly/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
    from <internal:/Users/nelly/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
    from /Users/nelly/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
    from /Users/nelly/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `block in require'
    from /Users/nelly/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:253:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/nelly/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `require'
    from /Users/nelly/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:191:in `spec'
    from /Users/nelly/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:950:in `establish_connection'
    from /Users/nelly/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:60:in `establish_connection'
    from /Users/nelly/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:136:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
    from /Users/nelly/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:71:in `instance_eval'
    from /Users/nelly/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:71:in `block in execute_hook'
    from /Users/nelly/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:62:in `with_execution_control'
    from /Users/nelly/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:67:in `execute_hook'
    from /Users/nelly/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:43:in `block in on_load'
    from /Users/nelly/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `each'
    from /Users/nelly/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `on_load'
    from /Users/nelly/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:132:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
    from /Users/nelly/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
    from /Users/nelly/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
    from /Users/nelly/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /Users/nelly/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
    from /Users/nelly/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/nelly/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /Users/nelly/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/nelly/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
    from /Users/nelly/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
    from /Users/nelly/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/nelly/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
    from /Users/nelly/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
    from /Users/nelly/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
    from /Users/nelly/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:361:in `initialize!'
    from /Users/nelly/code/knopfler81/leschner_ivan/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
    from config.ru:3:in `require_relative'
    from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    from /Users/nelly/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rack-2.2.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `eval'
    from /Users/nelly/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rack-2.2.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `new_from_string'
    from /Users/nelly/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rack-2.2.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:105:in `load_file'
    from /Users/nelly/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rack-2.2.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:66:in `parse_file'
    from /Users/nelly/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rack-2.2.7/lib/rack/server.rb:349:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
    from /Users/nelly/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rack-2.2.7/lib/rack/server.rb:249:in `app'
    from /Users/nelly/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:27:in `app'
    from /Users/nelly/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rack-2.2.7/lib/rack/server.rb:422:in `wrapped_app'
    from /Users/nelly/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:89:in `log_to_stdout'
    from /Users/nelly/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:51:in `start'
    from /Users/nelly/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:147:in `block in perform'
    from <internal:kernel>:90:in `tap'
    from /Users/nelly/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `perform'
    from /Users/nelly/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/thor-1.2.2/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    from /Users/nelly/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/thor-1.2.2/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
    from /Users/nelly/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/thor-1.2.2/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
    from /Users/nelly/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/command/base.rb:65:in `perform'
    from /Users/nelly/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
    from /Users/nelly/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
    from <internal:/Users/nelly/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
    from <internal:/Users/nelly/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
    from /Users/nelly/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
    from /Users/nelly/code/knopfler81/leschner_ivan/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/nelly/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
    from /Users/nelly/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
    from /Users/nelly/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    from /Users/nelly/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
    from /Users/nelly/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/nelly/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
    from /Users/nelly/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from <internal:/Users/nelly/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
    from <internal:/Users/nelly/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
    from /Users/nelly/code/knopfler81/leschner_ivan/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
    from ./bin/rails:3:in `load'
    from ./bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

Comment: You can see from the logs that the ruby version being used in your app is 3.2.2, not 2.4.4.  Rails 5 is not going to play nicely with Ruby 3.2.2 -- need to set your ruby version to 2.4.4, and give that a shot.

Comment: Thx, I edited my question because I already tried to install an older version of ruby but it keeps failing....

Comment: ok sorry I will edit and ask another question sorry